# Why does my "if" statement in python not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering why my "if" statement isn't working. I get asked for the input, and nothing happens after. It won't print out whether it is A, B, C or D.

```py
def main():
    printLetterGradeFromNumber(input("The grade as a number: "))

def printLetterGradeFromNumber(number_grade):

    A = range(90, 100)
    B = range(80, 89)
    C = range(70, 79)
    D = range(60, 69)

    if number_grade == A:
         print("That student gets an A")
    elif number_grade == B:
        print("That student gets a B")
    elif number_grade == C:
        print("That student gets a C")
    elif number_grade == D:
        print("That student gets a D")

    return number_grade


main()
```

Comment: you want `in` not `==`

Comment: you should say `if number_grade in A` and not if `number_grade == A`. Do you think `91==(90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99)`??? the answer to that question makes your if statement not work

Comment: creating ranges is not a very efficient check for this, you'd be better off looking at the  duplicate of the duplicate

Comment: You need to convert your `number_grade` to `int(number_grade)` for comparison

Answer (score 4):

#### There are two issues:

- The `input`, inside `main`, needs to be converted to an `int`

  - Currently, the `input` is a `str`, which will never be `True` when tested for membership inside of `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`
  - Example: `'90' == 90` compares as `False`, so `'90' in A` is `False`
- Use the [membership operator, `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations), instead of the [comparison operator, `==`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

```py
def main():
    printLetterGradeFromNumber(int(input("The grade as a number: ")))

def printLetterGradeFromNumber(number_grade):
    A = range(90, 100)
    B = range(80, 89)
    C = range(70, 79)
    D = range(60, 69)

    if number_grade in A:
         print("That student gets an A")
    elif number_grade in B:
        print("That student gets a B")
    elif number_grade in C:
        print("That student gets a C")
    elif number_grade in D:
        print("That student gets a D")

    return number_grade

main()
```

#### Output:

```
The grade as a number:  90
That student gets an A
```

### Alternate implementation:

- [Don’t Forget NumPy!](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/#dont-forget-numpy)
- [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)

  - `digitize` returns the `index` of `value`, within `bins`.  `value < 60` returns `index = 0`, while `value >= 90` returns `index = 4`.
  - A letter grade is found, using the `index` of `grades`.  As such, the order of `grades` must correspond to `bins`.

```py
from numpy import digitize

def print_letter_grade():
    value = int(input('The grade as a number: '))
    grades = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
    index = digitize(value, bins=[60, 70, 80, 90])
    print(f'The student gets an {grades[index]}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
def printLetterGradeFromNumber(number_grade):

    #A = range(90, 100)
    #B = range(80, 89)
    #C = range(70, 79)
    #D = range(60, 69)

    if number_grade >= 90 and number_grade <= 100:
         print("That student gets an A")
    if number_grade >= 80 and number_grade <= 89:
         print("That student gets a B")
    elif number_grade >= 70 and number_grade <= 79:
        print("That student gets a C")
    elif number_grade >= 60 and number_grade <= 69:
        print("That student gets a D")

   return number_grade
```

Answer (score 0):

range(90, 100) equals (90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99)

You need to use 'in' operator

```
    if number_grade in A:
         print("That student gets an A")
    elif number_grade in B:
        print("That student gets a B")
    elif number_grade in C:
        print("That student gets a C")
    elif number_grade in D:
        print("That student gets a D")
```

Comment: `range` returns a generator

Comment: @andole  `range` returns a range object, not a list or a tuple. Among other things, this object can test if a value is in the range without generating the values.

Comment: I know it doesn't return a tuple or a list. What I said in the answer is what range means in the given context. I edited the answer to make it a little less misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to define a function. Use a “For” loop.

Set your grades to A=range(90, 101). B=range(80, 90), C=range(70, 80), D=range(60, 70)

When you use ranges python excludes the upper bound integer